# How does the console window handle JavaScript arithmetic assignment internally? Where is the returned value coming from?

Tags: javascript, console, variable-assignment, read-eval-print-loop

I've been playing around with JavaScript a lot more lately, and this course I am going through keeps on emphasizing the importance of knowing JavaScript from within.

So I've got this kind of a weird question, it's mainly just me trying to understand how JavaScript works internally.

Let's say I do the following computation in the console:

```
>> x = 1
<  1
>> x = x + 2
<  3
```

The '3' that is being returned there, where is it coming from exactly?

Like is it evaluating 'x + 2' first, then returns 3 and sets the value of x in memory to 3? Or would it evaluate 'x + 2', save it in x's memory space, then return the value of x from that same memory space?

Or maybe even just alter x's value in its memory space without moving it around, then returns the value of x?

I would also appreciate any source on how I could learn more about the internal workings of JavaScript too, to answer more questions like these.

Thanks!

Comment: Value printed in console is nothing but output of the last operation.. Try `x=x+2,name=100;`.. Will give you better idea..

Comment: Yup, how that output itself is being calculated in memory (in relevance to the variables) is what I am more concerned about. Basically trying to understand what the console is returning exactly, just to know JS insides better.

Comment: This is more of a REPL thing than a JavaScript thing I'd say

Comment: All right.. I thought this question is more about Chrome-Dev-Tools...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, just googled and read on REPL, and it sounds like you're spot on. Will add it to the tags, thanks!

Comment: The console outputs the result of the last expression. An assignment is an expression. The `3` that is output is coming from the same place as the `1` output on the previous line. Think about what happens if you say (in the console or in your web page) `x = y = z = z + 1;` or if you do an assignment inside an `if` condition like `if(x=true){}`...

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever worked on a terminal based system like Unix, it would be easier to understand what's going on. Think of the console a a type of `bash` terminal. If you type a command into a command line terminal and press the enter key the it will respond with an output or some times even an error.

Something similar is happening in the Chrome console. Every time you open a Chrome console it retains a session where it stores your variables and functions. And when you call or use the same variable or function it is simply returning that value.

BTW when you type something like

```
>> x = 1
```

what happens internally is the that a new property called `x` in created in the global `window` object. So `x = 1` is same as `window.x = 1`. This is how the console can remember you assignments and use it later when you call it.

I hope I managed to confuse you, so I will stop here.

Comment: Nope, no confusion caused! The course I am going through right now actually explained the window part well, `this.x` also works too :) – Although I am looking more for how variables are 'dealt' with in memory by JS, like the returned value, where is it coming from exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can take your example further to see its logic like

```
>> x = 1
<  1
>> y = x = x + 2
<  3
>> x == y
<  true
```

It is basically output of the line. Some features you have seen on your browser are implemented on top of Javascript engine. Here is [my favorite talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) slightly related to the topic.